# Understanding output of lvdisplay in LVM/Linux

Tags: lvm

I just need to know the meaning of following fields in lvdisplay output

```
root@sandbox: lvdisplay rootvg/swaplv | grep -i '# open'
 # open                 2
root@sandbox: lvdisplay rootvg/swaplv | grep -i 'Segments'
  Segments              1
```

Comment: Please, don't cross-post. Be patient, not every question gets answered in 24 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`# open` - how many processes are currently using the device.

For example if you run `dd if=/dev/rootvg/swaplv of=/dev/null`, `dd` will open the swaplv. The `# open` will increase by 1. Once `dd` terminates, `# open` decreases by 1. If `# open` is 0, nothing is using it and the LV can be safely deactivated.

`Segments` refers to fragmentation of LV. If you grow the LV, but there is no consecutive space available, it will create a new segment in a free part of your physical volume(s). The number of segments is the number of fragments so to speak.

For example my HDD/TV LV has 4 segments and it looks like this:

```
# lvs -o lv_name,size,seg_size,devices HDD/TV
  LV   LSize SSize   Devices      
  TV   2.10t 698.56g /dev/dm-8(0) 
  TV   2.10t 698.56g /dev/dm-3(0) 
  TV   2.10t 698.56g /dev/dm-2(0) 
  TV   2.10t  52.31g /dev/dm-1(32)
```

So the total size of 2.1t is achieved by 3 segments with 698.56g each, plus one segment of 52.31g.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I am totally satisfied with your answer but just want to clear one doubt if # open number of process using that device then why it is showing only 1 for my rootlv that is used as root fs and there are more then one process are using that fs.

Comment: Well, that's indirect usage. Your Program `open()`s Your Files, whereas Your File System `open()`s the Block Device. No matter how many files are in use in the filesystem, if the filesystem itself has only one handle on the device, the `# open` count of that device remains 1. In any case, filesystems have their own usage counts, and prevent themselves from being umounted while any file is in use. Also compare `lsof` / `fuser`.